# Laravel - update data from array

Tags: arrays, laravel

I want update an array of ids.

[image]

Eloquent Query

```
$my_ids = json_encode($request->post('my_ids'));
Lead::whereIn('id', $my_ids)->update(['op' => 2]);
```

but I need to pass a string with comma.

[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: $my_ids is an array from strings. If you want update all of them you should use foreach:              foreach($my_ids as $id){Lead::whereIn('id', $id)->update(['op' => 2]); }

Comment: In this way not runs a lot of query? I'd like to make a query only.

Comment: In your solution, convert $my_ids to int.like this:(int)$my_ids

Comment: tried, no error but doesn't work.

Comment: can you show picture of your dd($my_ids )?

Comment: added screen to my question.

Comment: Your variable is string. Use json_decode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the ids you receive from post request is object string so you need to decode that string in order to get an array.

```
$my_ids = json_decode($request->post('my_ids'), true);
Lead::whereIn('id', $my_ids)->update(['op' => 2]);
```